# How to read predicate formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I have just started learning about predicate logic and am having some trouble in figuring out how to actually read the formula as as a sentence.

```
¬(marriedTo(X , Y ) ⇒ marriedTo(Y , X ))
```

Would I read the above formula as;

```
if X is not married to Y, the Y is married to X
```

?

Comment: Watch the parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the grouping of terms, the negation operator acts on the entirety of the implication $$\mathop{\mathrm{marriedTo}}(X,Y) \rightarrow \mathop{\mathrm{marriedTo}}(Y,X).$$

The above formula can be translated as:

> If X is married to Y, then Y is married to X.

Therefore, the negation of that formula, $$\neg(\mathop{\mathrm{marriedTo}}(X,Y) \rightarrow \mathop{\mathrm{marriedTo}}(Y,X)),$$ can be translated as:

> *It is not the case that* if X is married to Y then Y is married to X.

In other words, the formula in question asserts that $X$ being married to $Y$ does *not* guarantee $Y$ is married to $X$. The predicate $\mathop{\mathrm{marriedTo}}$ is, therefore, not symmetric.

Comment: thank you that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You can do better than "It is not the case that ....". Note that $\neg(p\to q) \equiv (p\land \neg q)$, so the formula is equivalent to
$$\text{marriedTo}(X,Y)\land \neg \, \text{marriedTo}(Y,X)
$$
or "X is married to Y, but Y is not married to X".